# Two different manpages for strftime?

Tags: strftime, manpage

I'm baffled. In one tmux pane, I can see an entry for `%Z` and `%z` with `manpage strftime`. Yet in another pane, I only see `%z` but not `%Z`. Both manpages say:

`STRFTIME(3)              BSD Library Functions Manual              STRFTIME(3)`

at the top.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something goofy was going on with wrapping. I widened the pane and the problem was resolved.